# Online Payment gateway which accepts gambling

Tags: web-development, programming, mobile, web, online-payment

I'm looking for a payment gateway, so far my only option is skrill

- It must work on mobile and the web
- It must accept a wide range of payment methods
- It shouldn't have a policy against gambling/betting category
- It should be available for all countries, I'm not in USA.
- It should have ready to use libraries, in at least PHP and Java
- It should be free to use and have reasonable fees.

Answer (score 1):

[BrainTreePayments](http://braintreepayments.com/codenewbie)

**Go global with ease**

> Almost anywhere in the world your buyers are located, we’ve got you
> covered with the tools you need to grow internationally. With one
> simple integration, your business can accept online and mobile
> payments in 130+ currencies and 44 countries.

**Acceptable Use Policy** [Link](https://www.braintreepayments.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy)

> You may not use the Payment Services in connection with any product,
> service, transaction or activity that involves:
>
> 6.bidding fee auctions
>
> 26.gambling (including but not limited to lotteries, Internet gaming, contests,
> sweepstakes, or offering of prizes as an inducement to purchase goods
> or services) (exceptions apply in some countries and if you get our
> prior written approval)

But you need to check the terms based on your country at:
[Bank agreements as applicable based on your region/country](https://www.braintreepayments.com/legal)

**Client SDKs:**

> iOS, Android, Web/JavaScript

**Server SDKs:**

> Ruby, Python, PHP, Node.js, Java, .NET

**Payment Methods:**

> PayPal, Credit Cards, Venmo, Apple Pay, Android Pay, UnionPay (Beta),
> Visa Checkout

**Personal Note:**

- I collected these from their website. You need to double check and
  read everything.
- I about the Gambling you'd better to ask them directly.   I
- also linked to the webpage as a codenewbie referrer cause that's where I heard about this service.